# PHPUnit upgrade from 9 to 10 exit code 1 when no code coverage driver available

Tags: php, phpunit

I've recently upgraded a project that used PHPUnit 9 to PHPUnit 10.

`phpunit.xml` for PHPUnit 9:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
        <report>
            <clover outputFile="clover.xml"/>
            <html outputDirectory="reports" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
</phpunit>
```

After upgrading to PHPUnit 10 and running the test suite:

```
There was 1 PHPUnit test runner deprecation:

1) Your XML configuration validates against a deprecated schema. Migrate your XML configuration using "--migrate-configuration"!
```

I migrated the configuration. Now I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/10.2/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage>
        <report>
            <clover outputFile="clover.xml"/>
            <html outputDirectory="reports" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
</phpunit>
```

Using PHPUnit 9, it would run and exit code 0.

```
root@141d4f8da80d:/var/www# composer exec phpunit
PHPUnit 9.6.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Warning:       No code coverage driver available

..................                                                18 / 18 (100%)

Time: 00:03.216, Memory: 32.00 MB

OK (18 tests, 73 assertions)
```

However, now with PHPUnit 10, it runs and exit code 1.

```
root@141d4f8da80d:/var/www# composer exec phpunit
PHPUnit 10.2.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.2.3
Configuration: /var/www/phpunit.xml

..................                                                18 / 18 (100%)

Time: 00:03.157, Memory: 34.00 MB

There was 1 PHPUnit test runner warning:

1) No code coverage driver available

WARNINGS!
Tests: 18, Assertions: 73, Warnings: 1.
Script phpunit handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 1
```

I've also upgraded `phpunit/phpcov` to `^9.0` to be compatible with `phpunit/phpunit` `^10`.

Is there a way to use the old method where it would print a warning that there is no coverage driver available, or, in the environments where there is no code coverage driver available, run with `--no-coverage`

```
root@141d4f8da80d:/var/www# composer exec phpunit -- --no-coverage
PHPUnit 10.2.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.2.3
Configuration: /var/www/phpunit.xml

..................                                                18 / 18 (100%)

Time: 00:02.985, Memory: 34.00 MB

OK (18 tests, 73 assertions)
```

Thanks!

---

It appears from [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5199#issuecomment-1437122132) that this is intentional and might be changed by using `failOnWarning`.